# Appending jquery element with other jquery element in loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop

```
function test() {
    var a = $('<p>'),
        b = $('<div>')

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        b.append(a)
    }

    console.log(b)
}
```

This function creates 1  element with 1

element inside it. Why there is not 10

elements? How can I append as many

element as many times loop goes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append()` function move your object.
You should use `clone()` before `append()`

```
function test() {
    var a = $('<p>'),
        b = $('<div>')

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        b.append(a.clone())
    }

    console.log(b)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you append an element, as it has only one parent, you remove it from its ancient location.

So you must clone it here before appending :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    b.append(a.clone())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    b = b.append(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new element each time through the loop, not reuse the same element, since an element can only be in one place in the DOM.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    b.append($("<p>"));
}
```